# Clicking on a div unable to show or hide the text using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

As i am fetching the data from database and displaying it in front end.Need to display only job name once i click on more info text it should display the rest of the text and clicking on more info again the text should be hided.

Now it is displaying all the text at the time page loading only once clicking on more info it is hiding the text and showing the text.

Script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#music").click(function() {
        $("#musicinfo").toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
                  <span class="digit"><?php echo $r->job_name ;?></span>
                  <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                    <div class="moreinfo" id="music" >More Info</div>
                        <div id="musicinfo">            

                            <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
                            <p class="jobdes"><?php echo $r->job_description ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Desired Skills & Experience</h3>
                            <p class="desiredskills"><?php echo $r->skills_experience ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
                            <p class="educationalqua"><?php echo $r->qualification ;?></p>

                            <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
                            <ul class="rolesand">
                                <li class="rolesandres"><?php echo $r->roles_responsibilities;?></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
                            <p class="whatweoffer"><?php echo $r->what_we_offer ;?></p>

             <h3  class="job">Share this job</h3>
                            <div class="facebookaccount"><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"data-layout="button_count"></div></div>
                            <div class="twitteraccount"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>
                            <div class="linkedinaccount"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
                            <div class="googleaccount"><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"></div></div>                                
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the div would be hidden on-load and would be visible only when you click on "More info":

```js
$(".moreinfo").on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
#musicinfo {
  display: none;
}

.moreinfo {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
  <span class="digit">JOB NAME</span>
  <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
  <div class="moreinfo" id="music">More Info</div>
  <div id="musicinfo">

    <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
    <p class="jobdes">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Desired Job Description</h3>
    <p class="desiredskills">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
    <p class="educationalqua">
      Educational Qualification
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
    <ul class="rolesand">
      <li class="rolesandres">
        Roles and Responsibilities
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
    <p class="whatweoffer">
      What we offer
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Share this job</h3>
    <div class="facebookaccount">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="twitteraccount"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
      <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="linkedinaccount"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
    <div class="googleaccount">
      <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="moreinfo" id="music">More Info</div>
  <div id="musicinfo">

    <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
    <p class="jobdes">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Desired Job Description</h3>
    <p class="desiredskills">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
    <p class="educationalqua">
      Educational Qualification
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
    <ul class="rolesand">
      <li class="rolesandres">
        Roles and Responsibilities
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
    <p class="whatweoffer">
      What we offer
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Share this job</h3>
    <div class="facebookaccount">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="twitteraccount"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
      <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="linkedinaccount"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
    <div class="googleaccount">
      <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="moreinfo" id="music">More Info</div>
  <div id="musicinfo">

    <h3 class="job">Job Description</h3>
    <p class="jobdes">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Desired Job Description</h3>
    <p class="desiredskills">
      Job Description
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Educational Qualification</h3>
    <p class="educationalqua">
      Educational Qualification
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Roles and Responsibilities</h3>
    <ul class="rolesand">
      <li class="rolesandres">
        Roles and Responsibilities
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="job">What we offer</h3>
    <p class="whatweoffer">
      What we offer
    </p>

    <h3 class="job">Share this job</h3>
    <div class="facebookaccount">
      <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="twitteraccount"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
      <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="linkedinaccount"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
    <div class="googleaccount">
      <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>career/careers/<?php echo $r ->jobs_name ;?>"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: same answer i was preparing  on this https://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/JJVaem . Except the pointer which is a nice touch.

Comment: Thanks @DincaAdrian!

Comment: @MilanChheda It is working for only one data if there is more than 3 the rest it is not working

Comment: Updated the code with 3 more. And changed the code to use 'class' and not ID as IDs are unique.

Comment: @MilanChheda there is an option to sahre this post in facebook and all but it is not displaying those option it is displaying only linkedin

Comment: @MilanChheda if i use #musicinfo {
  display: none;
} then the social sharing is not working

Comment: @user8001297 - That's a sample code. I thought, you can take it ahead and tweak it to your way. Anyways, I have updated it.

Comment: here it is displaying only twitter the rest it is not showing and the problem is it is not showing in mozilla

Comment: @user8001297 - IF you see and understand, those are PHP codes which wouldn't get executed here.

Comment: Php is working fine not having any problem  with php it is not displying the facebook buttons onlt

Comment: in mozilla unable to display social sharing buttons facebook,twitter and google

Comment: those buttons would be having their own CSS & JS. You need to check those.

Comment: As I mentioned above there would be additional CSS and JS that you need to check. Above is a sample working code which you can use as a reference to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to hide the div on load? Right now it shows and will hide the first time you click the `more info` button?

This can simply be solved by adding display: none in the stylesheet for the `moreinfo` div.

Answer (score 0):

Use display: none; for #musicinfo ...

```
#musicinfo{
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially what you not required to display or what you do not want to show on screen set the properties of that div to `display: none` after that you can show it on click of more info text by setting click event and animate property of jquery like

```
$(#more-info).on('click',function(){
$('.job').css('display':'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fix this line `<p class=""desiredskills"><?php echo $r->skills_experience ;?></p>`

```
<p class="desiredskills"><?php echo $r->skills_experience ;?></p>
```

and try again

https://jsfiddle.net/he4zfxge/

When you use ID, the first element will work 
Try This
https://jsfiddle.net/he4zfxge/2/

Comment: If there are more than 4 job types it is working only for one

Comment: ok because you use id for your element fix this problem by change id to class  div#music -> div.music  And <div class="moreinfo" id="music">   <div class="moreinfo music">

Answer (score 0):

try this, if #music is a button:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#music").on("click", function() {
        $("#musicinfo").show();
    });
    $("#music").off("click", function() {
        $("#musicinfo").hide();
    });
});
```

I think there is a `</div>` missing

Comment: Its working only for the first data if the data is more than one it is not working for the rest of the data

Answer (score 0):

Change id attribute into class. In your html code, define music and musicinfo id as class.

**Note:- html Validate-** You can not defined more than one id with same name in html page.

**Write javascript code, which is given below-**

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
              <span class="digit">test1</span>
              <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                <div class="moreinfo">More Info</div>
                    <div class="musicinfo">            
                      test 1  description   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
              <span class="digit">test2</span>
              <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                <div class="moreinfo">More Info</div>
                    <div class="musicinfo">            
                      test 2  description      
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="digitalmarketingassociate">
              <span class="digit">test3</span>
              <div class="applynow">Apply Now</div>
                <div class="moreinfo">More Info</div>
                    <div class="musicinfo">            
                      test 3    description     
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(' .musicinfo').hide();
    $(".moreinfo").click(function() {
        $('.musicinfo').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.musicinfo').toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```